# Request DTO map to Domain Model

Tags: servicestack

I have the following Domain Model:

```
public class DaybookEnquiry : Entity
{
    public DateTime EnquiryDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EnquiryType")]
    public int DaybookEnquiryTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual DaybookEnquiryType EnquiryType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DaybookQuoteLine> QuoteLines { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is inside of a project named `DomainModel`. `Entity` is just a base class which my domain models inherit from, it contains an `Id` field.

I then have other projects inside my solution called `ServiceInterface` and `ServiceModel`. `ServiceInterface` contains all my services for my application and `ServiceModel` contains my DTO's and routes etc.. I'm trying to follow the guidelines set out here: [Physical Project Structure](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure)

My `EnquiriesService` contains a method to create a new enquiry in my database using a repository:

```
public void Post(CreateEnquiry request)
{
    // Not sure what to do here..
    // _repository.Insert(request);
}
```

My `CreateEnquiry` request looks like so:

```
[Api("POST a single Enquiry for Daybook.")]
[Route("/enquiries", "POST")]
public class CreateEnquiry : IReturnVoid { }
```

As you can see, the `CreateEnquiry` request object is empty. Do I need to add properties to it to match my Domain Model and then use AutoMapper or something similar to map the fields to my Domain Model and pass that into my repository?

The `Insert` method on my repository looks like so:

```
public virtual void Insert(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
    {
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Your Service request, in this case `CreateEnquiry` needs to have all the properties you need in order to do whatever it is you want to do!

I've seen two different models for Create vs Update:

- Use one request objects called, say, `SetEnquiry` that has a nullable id field.  When null and using the `POST` HTTP verb, it internally creates a new object.  And when not null and using the `PATCH` HTTP verb, it internally updates an object.  You can use ServiceStack's implementation of `AbstractValidator<T>` to add logic such as *if POST then id field needs to be null; and if PATCH then id field cannot be null*.  This will help ensure your data is always as it needs to be.
- Create two request objects -- one for Create and one for Update.  The Create doesn't even have an id field, and the Update has one and requires it.  You can use the same validation technique used above, except applied to each class independently, so you don't need the conditional check of *if this verb do this; if that verb do that*.

How you map to your data model is up to you.  You can use something like AutoMapper or you can use ServiceStack's built-in `TranslateTo` and `PopulateWith` methods.  I personally take a middle ground: I created my own object extension methods called `MapTo` and `MapFrom` that interally call `TranslateTo` and `PopulateWith` respectively.  Why did I do this?  Because then I control those extensions inside my own namespaces and when I need to do special mappings (like a column name doesn't match up, or one object is more complex than the other, or I simply want to ignore a particular column from one of the objects) I simply overload the `MapTo` and `MapFrom` with explicit types, giving it higher specificity than the generic methods.

So back to your question specifically.  Assuming you're using the built in `TranslateTo` your service method might look like this:

```
public void Post(CreateEnquiry request)
{
    _repository.Insert(request.TranslateTo<Enquiry>());
}
```

One more thing: I generally return the object itself when doing a Create and Update.  As fields can change (auto-calculated fields, for example) I like to return the object back to the caller.  This is preference and has no real bearing on the answer I'm giving you.  Just throwing it out there!